# Need to Tweak Pre-loader script to not load on a page that loads in under 1 second

Tags: javascript, html, delay, preloader

php guy here not a javascript guy. support a site with the below code, need to adjust the preloader to wait and see if the page loaded within a second, if not, then to display the image. Am pretty clueless and have search for examples, the ones I found extend the preloader time, which isnt what i want, here is the code:

```
<script>
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var state = document.readyState
        if (state == 'interactive') {
            document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility="hidden";
        } else if (state == 'complete') {
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('interactive');
                document.getElementById('load').style.visibility="hidden";
                document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility="visible";
            },1);
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="load"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some irony in trying to do some DOM manipulation (like your code does) *before* the document is ready.  Usually, you want to avoid DOM manipulation until *after* the document is ready.  I recommend a slightly different and simpler approach.  Control the visibility of your loading image via CSS.

Currently, your `#load` image is visible by default.  To make it hidden by default, add `visibility: hidden;` to your `#load` style rule.  Next, add a rule for `.loading #load` that overrides the `visibility` to make it visible.  This means that `#load` will only be visible when one of its a parent elements has a class of `loading`, thus activating the rule that overrides `visibility`.

```css
#load {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    background:url("../images/loading.gif") no-repeat fixed center rgba(255,255,255,1);
    visibility: hidden;
}

.loading #load {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

With your CSS in place, the JavaScript is fairly straightforward.  We are going use `setTimeout` to set a delay of 1 second (1000 ms) and then run a function.  That function checks to see if the document is ready, and if not, adds the `loading` class to the root HTML element, thus allowing the `#load` image to be visible 1 second after the script tag was parsed.

We also add an event listener on the document for the `load` event (which happens immediately after `document.readyState` is set to `complete`).  When that event fires, it removes the `loading` class from the root element.  If this happens to run before 1 second, that's ok.  It doesn't matter that the root element doesn't have the `loading` class yet.  It never will, in that case, because it only gets added if the `readyState` is not yet `complete`.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.readyState != "complete") {
        document.documentElement.classList.add("loading");
    }
}, 1000);
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("loading");
});
```

You should familiarize yourself with [all of the possible values of `document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState#Values).  It's possible that you want to hide your loading image as soon as the document is `interactive`.  In this state, not every image has been downloaded, but the document has been fully parsed and is ready for DOM manipulation.  In that case, you would listen for the `readystatechange` event instead of the `load` event:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.readyState == "loading") {
        document.documentElement.classList.add("loading");
    }
}, 1000);
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (document.readyState != "loading") { // either interactive or complete
        document.documentElement.classList.remove("loading");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One second from when? Remember that your Javascript code, which would check this, also needs to be loaded and parsed.

In any case, this should send you in the right direction. Note that `#contents` starts out hidden.

```
<div id="contents" style="visibility:hidden">Contents</div>
<div id="loader" style="visibility:visible"></div>
<script>
   setTimeout(function() {
      checkDocumentState();
   }, 1000);

  function checkDocumentState() {
     var state = document.readyState;
     if (state === 'loading') {
        // do something if you need to 
        // or do nothing
        console.log('Still loading');
        return;
     } else if (state === 'interactive') {
        //do something if you need to 
        // or do nothing
        console.log('Now getting images and stuff');
        return;
     } else if (state === 'complete') {
        // Make the content visible 
        // Do whatever else you need to do
        console.log('Everything is here. Show the contents.');
        document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility="visible";
     }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried putting this code in but then the loader never went away.

Comment: @Whodatt I'm curious why. Did you add the code to hide your loader? I didn't have it in my code because I thought it was obvious. I've added it now in the code.

Comment: Hi ba_ul. As a PHP guy who has to support this website (new) nothing in javascript  is obvious to me :-)